# How to define entry point in C++/CLI DLL with command line argument /ENTRY

Tags: dll, c++-cli

There is an option in cl.exe to define custom entry point in a DLL with command line attribute /ENTRY. Unfortunately, it does not provide an example of how to use it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f9t8842e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

I created managed C++ DLL with support of /CLR and replaced name of main function with "Start":

```
int Start(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return 0;
}
```

Then I try to compile this DLL from command line with this BAT command:

```
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\cl.exe" ^
    /clr /Fo /Z7 /D "NDEBUG" ^
    /ENTRY:Start ^
    "..\Links\Links.cpp"
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

```
LNK1561: Entry point must be defined
```

**Question**: What exactly should I pass as /ENTRY argument?

**Edit**: as it was mentioned in Hans' comment below, function used to be an entry point in the DLL needs to have another signature so I corrected example above. Function presented below is an example of entry point for EXE file, particularly because it has managed type among its parameters.

```
int Start(array<String ^> ^ argc)
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The entrypoint for a DLL has always been, and still is for a C++/CLI assembly, a function named "DllMain".  Whose signature doesn't look anything like your Start() method.  A bug that the linker doesn't warn you about.  It will end poorly, you don't get strings, the return value matters a great deal and it will be called multiple times.

Comment: @Hans Passant: you are right, I was trying to compile this project in both ways - as either DLL or EXE, function mentioned in the first version of this question could be compiled if output is EXE file, if I try to compile it as DLL it informs me that function's signature is wrong so i corrected it to be a DLL's function.

Comment: That still isn't the correct signature for a DLL entry point.  Besides, specifying `/ENTRY` on a managed assembly is a really bad idea, because now all the .NET Framework support code in the C++ runtime library won't be executed.  Just leave the entrypoint provided by the library alone, and provide a function named `DllMain` which the library entry point will call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Specifying `/ENTRY` on a managed assembly is a really bad idea, because now all the .NET Framework support code in the C++ runtime library won't be executed.  Initializers of global C++ objects won't get a chance to run either.  And you may get memory leaks on worker threads, because the C++ runtime library is smart enough to perform thread-local initialization when needed, but because it isn't receiving thread detach events, it won't be able to clean up.  On the other hand, C++/CLI assemblies *always* dynamically link to the runtime DLLs, so at least that library `DllMain` will receive thread notifications, and resources used by the runtime itself won't be leaked.

Just leave the `DllMainCRTStartup` entrypoint provided by the library alone, and provide a function named `DllMain` which the library entry point will call.

There is plenty of documentation on MSDN concerning initialization code in C++/CLI managed assemblies:

- [Initialization of Mixed Assemblies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/initialization-of-mixed-assemblies)

One of the important things to take away from that is that the `DllMain` signature (which again, is NOT the actual entrypoint, it is called from the library-provided entrypoint), is

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(
  _In_  HINSTANCE hinstDLL,
  _In_  DWORD fdwReason,
  _In_  LPVOID lpvReserved
);
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, although, in any case I'd like to mention that I was able to add new C# WinForms project to my solution and call it from my custom entry point so I think that code in DllMainCRTStartup is not so critical even though it is recommended.

Comment: @SkyScanner: I added some more explanation on some specific ramifications.

Answer (score 0):

Silly me. Option /ENTRY is an argument for link.exe, not for cl.exe

With the following BAT script I can force my assembly to have custom entry point. The only thing is that in some reason in this case linker requires to set type of the project directly with /SUBSYSTEM option.

```
"c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\bin\link.exe" ^
    /DLL /ENTRY:Start ^
    /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE ^
    /WX ^
    /OUT:Links.dll ^
    "Links.obj"
```